# How to automatically begin editing when adding a new row to a datagrid in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, focus, windows-community-toolkit

I have a community toolkit datagrid bound to an observable collection. I also have an "add" button bound to a command that adds a new element to the collection and thus adds a new row to the datagrid. Now I want to automatically start editing the first cell of the new row when the button is clicked.
I tried adding this to the end of my command:

```cs
MyDataGrid.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
MyDataGrid.SelectedIndex = MyCollection.Count;
MyDataGrid.CurrentColumn = MyDataGrid.Columns[0];
MyDataGrid.BeginEdit();
```

Though this only works when the focus was already on the datagrid before the button is clicked. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you check the [WindowsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) source code, you will know that it's by design. You could submit your 'Feature Request' on [Github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22feature+request%22).

Comment: @XavierXie this is supported, just not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in XAML Studio for the known namespaces in settings. It's an `ObservableCollection` bound to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.

In addition to having a button for the Add action and putting code in its callback, you need to add an event handler on the DataGrid for the `PreparingCellForEdit` event.

So in your add method, you can create a new element in your collection and start editing the new item like so:

```cs
        private void AddNamespaceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add new Row and begin editing
            KnownNamespaces.Insert(0, new XmlnsNamespace(string.Empty, string.Empty));

            NamespaceDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;

            NamespaceDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(NamespaceDataGrid.SelectedItem, null);

            NamespaceDataGrid.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);

            NamespaceDataGrid.BeginEdit();
        }
```

The next piece is the key for the DataGridTextColumn type to ensure the focus of the cell gets transferred to the focus of the TextBox inside when editing:

```cs
        private void NamespaceDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.EditingElement is TextBox t)
            {
                t.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
            }
        }
```

It's also important to note that the class that your ObservableCollection consists of should implement the `IEditableObject` interface to work properly with the DataGrid.

---

Here's my XAML for completeness:

```xml
<StackPanel Margin="{StaticResource SettingsSubheaderMargin}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="SettingsPanel_KnownNamespaces"
                                       Margin="0,8,0,12"
                                       Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" />
                            <Button x:Uid="SettingsPanel_KnownNamespaces_Button_Add" Click="AddNamespaceButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource VSCodeAppBarHeaderButtonStyle}">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="NamespaceDataGrid"
                                           MaxHeight="450"
                                           AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                           Background="{ThemeResource Brush-Blue-Dark-1}"
                                           CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                           CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                           IsReadOnly="False"
                                           ItemsSource="{x:Bind KnownNamespaces, Mode=OneWay}"
                                           PreparingCellForEdit="NamespaceDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit"
                                           RowEditEnded="DataGrid_RowEditEnded">
                            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells"
                                                             Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                                             FontSize="20"
                                                             Header="Shortcut" />
                                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells"
                                                             Binding="{Binding Path}"
                                                             FontSize="20"
                                                             Header="Namespace" />
                                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button x:Uid="SettingsPanel_KnownNamespaces_Button_Remove"
                                                    Click="RemoveNamespaceButton_Click"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource VSCodeAppBarHeaderButtonStyle}">
                                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Delete" />
                                            </Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                        </controls:DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
```

I use the RowEditEnding event to save my data model back to disk.